# Wrap next text in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any dynamic way to wrap next text.

```
<p>Enterprise integration platform</p>
```

Expected output:

```
<p>Enterprise <span>integration</span> platform</p>
```

I need to wrap any text which will appear after 'Enterprise'

Comment: What do you mean by _next text_?

Comment: I need to wrap any text which will appear after 'Enterprise'

Comment: `$("p").html(function() {
  var texts = this.textContent.split(" ");
  return texts[0]+" <span>"+texts[1]+"</span> "+texts[2];
});` - use https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ to find them

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will find all occurrences of paragraphs with the word Enterprise in them. You will need more processing if the word can occur after other words

```js
$("p:contains('Enterprise')").html(function() { 
  var texts = this.textContent.split(" "); 
  return texts.shift()+" <span>"+texts.shift()+"</span> "+texts.join(" ");
});
```

```css
span { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some stuff:</p>
<p>Enterprise integration platform</p>
<p>Enterprise architecture</p>
<p>Enterprise service as a service</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText.replace(/Enterprise (\S+)/, "Enterprise <span>$1</span>");
}
```

```css
/* just style to highlight span */
span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Enterprise integration platform</p>
```

Note that this regular expression will replace only first occurrence of `Enterprise`, if you need replace all occurrences you need to add `g` suffix: `/Enterprise (\S+)/g`.

I'm using regular expression here, I can explain it here

- `Enterprise` — obviously search for `Enterprise` text.
- `\S+` — search for one or more non-whitespace characters.
- `(\S+)` — capture this non-whitespace character group to replace using `$1`.

If need case-insensitive search for `Enterprise` you should rewrite replacing operator to `.replace(/(enterprise) (\S+)/i, "$1 <span>$2</span>")`.

Note that I'm using `i` suffix for case-insensitive search and capturing `enterprise` word because it can be in any case.